# What is the safest and most efficient way to remove multiple applications installed by 'sudo apt install gnome-*'?

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

I Accidentally ran `sudo apt install gnome-*` in terminal and a lot of applications were installed in my system. I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of all those apps that were installed by the command. Is there any way to sort by date and remove the unwanted apps?

Is it safe to run `sudo apt remove gnome-*?`

Comment: Well, It's "safe" in the sense that it probably won't burn down your home. But it will certainly remove your entire Gnome desktop, which some folks might consider quite catastrophic and emotionally wrenching. It's compounding your first bad decision (sorry, I mean "accident") with another bad decision.

Comment: If you accidentally remove the desktop environment, you can restore it with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding using "*" in `apt` commands wherever possible

Comment: it's fine u need to install needed things from console though

Answer (score 2):

Review the list of the packages that were actually installed.

Find that list at `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Remove only the packages on that list.

Comment: `$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log` -> nothing. I assume that happens when you have rebooted.

Comment: @Hannu not due to a reboot, but definitely when that log rotates on the 1st day of each month. A stock Ubuntu system will preserve last month's log also. It's in the same directory.

Comment: `$ ls -l /var/log/apt/ | wc -l` -> 
`28` -- so yes, there was a bunch more.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt remove gnome-*` will remove all packages that does match that,
also the ones that were install prior to your "mishap".

Now, what follows has not been **tried**, beware ;-)

1. Do
   `$ dpkg --list | grep -E "^ii[[:space:]]+gnome" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2 | sed -re "s/^/sudo apt uninstall /" > filename`
   then remove the lines below from that file (to keep them)...  *[ created on my 20.04 ubuntu ]*
2. save the file, exit the editor
3. do `source filename` from a terminal.

```
gnome-accessibility-themes
gnome-bluetooth
gnome-calculator
gnome-calendar
gnome-characters
gnome-clocks
gnome-control-center
gnome-control-center-data
gnome-control-center-faces
gnome-desktop3-data
gnome-disk-utility
gnome-font-viewer
gnome-getting-started-docs
gnome-initial-setup
gnome-keyring
gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64
gnome-logs
gnome-mahjongg
gnome-menus
gnome-mines
gnome-online-accounts
gnome-power-manager
gnome-screenshot
gnome-session-bin
gnome-session-canberra
gnome-session-common
gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon-common
gnome-shell
gnome-shell-common
gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
gnome-shell-extensions
gnome-startup-applications
gnome-sudoku
gnome-system-monitor
gnome-terminal
gnome-terminal-data
gnome-themes-extra:amd64
gnome-themes-extra-data
gnome-todo
gnome-todo-common
gnome-tweaks
gnome-user-docs
gnome-video-effects
```